# Adding window controller to NSDocument-based app ups retain count by two

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management, retain, nsdocument

I got an `NSDocument`-based app. In the document class, a window is created. This window controller is added in `-makeWindowControllers` (code below). If I check out the retain count of my controller (`[_windowController retainCount]`) right after adding it, the retain count equals 3. But why? I'd imagine it should be two? What happens in `-addWindowController:`?

```
 - (void)makeWindowControllers {

    NSLog(@"%li", (unsigned long)[[self windowController] retainCount]); // Outputs 1
    [self addWindowController:[self windowController]];
    NSLog(@"%li", (unsigned long)[_windowController retainCount]); // Outputs 3

}

- (ProjectWindowController *)windowController {

    if (!_windowController) { // Lazy loading
        _windowController = [ProjectWindowControllerYosemite new];
    }

    return _windowController;

}
```

Comment: `addWindowController` "Adds the specified window controller to this document’s list of attached window controllers and sets the document of the passed-in window controller.". Is the retainCount of 3 a problem?

Comment: Why does the retain count increase by 2? It causes problems in that, when I'm releasing the window controller upon termination, its `-dealloc` method never gets called.

Comment: Does the retainCount decrease by 2 when you call `removeWindowController`?

Comment: Made a test project, and that one ups the retain count by one, not by two. There must be something silly I'm overlooking in my code.

Comment: Turns out to be due to an `NSTimer` instance created in my custom window controller ; it keeps a strong reference to the controller (which is its target). I traced the additional retain by using the code [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5587553/3576399).

Comment: The retain count is useless.  Ignore it.  It'll never give you a definitive answer about anything.   In this case, it is an implementation detail.